# Score for answering a question: 15pts + # of question upvotes

Tags: feature-request, questions, answers, bounties, up-votes

Upvoting questions would increase the likelihood that someone would answer it.  Its a variation of the "put bounty on someone else's question" suggestion.

Comment: What about downvoted questions?

Comment: Or leftvoted questions!?

Comment: @Welbog: I rightvoted your last comment.  That's what the little flag is for, right?

Comment: @Pesto, no, that's for frontvoting, dummy.

Comment: @Welbog: You insulted me, so I should flag the comment.  But on the other hand, I already needlessly flagged one of your comments.  I guess it's a wash, you jerk.

Comment: MY friends please. There's no need for name calling. You're both equally jerkish and dumm-esque. Can't we all just agree that I'm still better than you are?

Comment: @devinb: I'll agree to that on the grounds that you accept that you suck and I hate you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Would cause gaming. People would up vote questions they answer regardless of whether or not it is a good one simply because there is a chance it would benefit them.

Comment: So make it +1 for everyone who upvoted it other than the one who supplied the chosen answer, if he indeed upvoted it.

Comment: I'm not following you. If people are aware that upvotes give more rep to accepted answers, but not if it's their own upvotes, then the only upvotes questions will get will be legitimate upvotes and pity upvotes, both of which they get already.

Comment: Why? I don't see how that follows. Do you think that people who answer questions upvote the question as a kind of bribe to have their answers chosen? They will be well aware that their upvotes won't apply if their answer is accepted. If anything it almost makes me think people will *not* upvote questions they answer to prevent other answers from getting the extra +1.

Comment: Yeah, I never considered how it would come full circle, you're right in that aspect. However personally I'm still against the idea because of the bias some question types get towards up votes.

Comment: I didn't think about the bias. It would weigh subjective and C# questions more than they already are, probably. But then again it would encourage lots of answers to really good questions. I don't know. I really don't know if it would be a good thing or a bad thing. Questions that get a lot of upvotes necessarily have gotten a lot of views, and probably have higher chance of being answered anyway (someone should check the latest dump to prove/disprove that), so there's probably no need to provide more incentive to have them answered.

Answer (score 2):

At first I misread this as 15 points + 10 x question upvotes, which I totally disagree with because it overvalues the upvotes.

But with a small extra incentive, maybe this is the nice middle ground between offering bounty on others' questions and the current system.

A couple questions for clarification:

- How would you have them work with the rep cap?  The same way as accepted answers always do?
- Suppose a question is at +3, and you get the accepted answer: +18 for you.  Then, two more people come along and upvote the question.  Do you get 2 more rep for those upvotes?
- What about downvotes?  Is it fair if they have no effect on this system?

Comment: Well, generally questions with a lot of downvotes get a lot of traffic, so good answers to downvoted questions will probably get more upvotes than if the questions weren't downvoted. Probably. So the lack of a bonus would be offset by this tendency. At least, it seems to me that downvoted questions get a lot of traffic.

Answer (score 0):

As noted this would be highly open for gaming. But that's not my concern.

This encourages noise. Lots and lots of noise. Questions with a lot of upvotes already have interest and answers. Tendency has already become that for any question with 5+ answers, at least two of them will be content-identical.

This solution provides more of an incentive to answer questions that don't need the help. On the other hand, there are questions with one or no upvotes because they aren't glamorous or sexy, and there's one answer so they do not show up on the 'unanswered' list anymore.

Those are the questions that need extra help, because there isn't interest in them. It's hard to come up with a solution that doesn't involve gaming, but those questions need help.

There was a recent question "What should I do if my partner aligns his brackets wrong", when I saw it, it had 6 upvotes. So, a lot of people would then want to add their two cents, in order to get a shot at getting the extra bonus.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this can only apply to questions which are over a certain age. Maybe they gain additional "Accept" points the longer they stay unanswered, which would encourage users to dig around in the older "unanswered" bin to find some additional rep and close out the languishing questions that have fallen off the front page.